# spacing for checkmark image of the check box in android

Tags: android, checkbox, padding

Hi i am trying to create a check box list which should looks like in the below image which will have space before and after checkmark image.

[image]

but when i am trying to create check box its is showing like the below image.

[image]

there is no space surrounds to check-mark image like i am showing the first image. If i use padding to check box component its like **"android:padding=50dp"** its giving space between check-mark image and text. But not giving space in the starting .i.e before Check-Mark image.
below is my xml layout for check box

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="15dp">
<CheckBox android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:button="@drawable/btn_check_square"
       android:background="@drawable/filter_item_background"
       android:textColor="@android:color/black"
       android:padding="5dp"
       android:text="check box text"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Any help to solve this issue is appreciated.

Comment: i have the same issue for RadioButtons also.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

this is resolved with below code.

```
<CheckBox
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/filter_item_background"
android:button="@android:color/transparent"                             //Make button null
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/btn_check_square"  //Create button in drawable
android:drawablePadding="20dp"                     //Set space between Text & CB     
android:padding="5dp"
android:text="check box text"
android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

Answer (score 15):

Try this (without custom graphics):

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@android:color/transparent"
    android:drawablePadding="8dp"
    android:text="CheckBox" />
```

It uses a little trick: As Checkbox is derived from Button, we can add a drawable and can now set a padding between label and drawable. As we do not acutally need a real icon, we use the transparent color instead.

Comment: Very clever solution. Setting the android:button="@null" or transparent in previous solutions didn't work for me. My text would collide with my custom button. But this solution worked for those looking to get a quick fix rather than creating their own checkbox.

Comment: It's a best working answer (with setting android:button="@drawable/custom_checkbox")

Comment: We would have a default checkbox animation with that solution? I believe not.

Answer (score 2):

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/filter_item_background"
    android:button="@null"                             //Make button null
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/btn_check_square"  //Create button in drawable
    android:drawablePadding="20dp"                     //Set space between Text & CB     
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="check box text"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

Comment: with this solution space is coming. but default check image is still visible. i tried the same pragmatically with the below code.
     cbox.setCompoundDrawablePadding(10);
     cbox.setButtonDrawable(0/null);
cbox.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(android.R.drawable.checkbox_off_background,0,0,0);

Comment: android:button="@null"   have you specified this line it works for me

Comment: if i change the android:button="@null" to @android:color/transparent. its working.

Comment: thanks raj i was working with API 17 so it works for me ...your idea is gud ya

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```
final float scale = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
checkbox.setPadding(checkbox.getPaddingLeft()
        + (int) (10.0f * scale + 0.5f),
        checkbox.getPaddingTop(),
        checkbox.getPaddingRight(),
        checkbox.getPaddingBottom());
```

Comment: its not working for me. its applying only for text. not for check mark image.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your checkbox:

```
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
```

Comment: this will not work for me. because if i use that layout_margin its giving space out side the checkbox component. i.e out side the background of the checkbox. but i want space inside the background of check box.

Comment: You're right -- but I think I know the reason for your problem -- it's your custom graphics for the button resp. the background. You should add a left and right spacing to the checkbox there and/or a left/right padding to your background image. You can achieve this by using 9 patch images (http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)

Comment: i tried without custom drawable also. i.e native checkbox without applying any button drawable. same problem is there.

Comment: I figured out how to do it (at least without custom images). See my new answer.